Kendo sticky cell content overlap
I have a kendo grid with sticky cell:
<td class="left k-grid-content-sticky k-table-td k-table-td cells-in-error-row" style="left: 169px; right: 0px;" role="gridcell">
    <div id="Name_validationMessage" role="tooltip" class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg k-popup" 
    style="margin: 0.5em;" data-for="Name" data-val-msg-for="Name">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span>
    <div class="k-tooltip-content">Name is required!</div>
        <div class="k-callout k-callout-n k-callout-validation k-callout-n-align-auto"></div>
    </div>
</td>

td has the following css rules:
.k-grid .k-grid-content-sticky{
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
}

I would like that the Name_validationMessage div appears over the cell. In this state hald of the Name_validationMessage div element is hidden by the sticky cell.
I have tried change position and z-index of Name_validationMessage div element, but without success.
I attached a picture about my issue. As you can see validation messages on the right side appear well, but thouse cells haven't got sticky property. Thank you!

